# Block Tools->Addons->Plugins in Firefox !

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

How can i block anyone from being able to modify the Tools->Addons->Plugins tab in Firefox?

I've had some some issues with some computers at work and i don't want to allow anyone to be able to uninstall the plugins from the Addons tab.

Is there any extension for this?

Or how could i do this programatically?

Thanks a lot!
Alex!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lock the Add-ons window with a password using this add-on :)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/public-fox/

Comment: I nice suggestion, but as one of the reviews says `...but it can be bypassed by booting [Firefox] into safe mode.`, which is worth keeping in mind as it reduces its usefulness to basically being security by obscurity (ie, not really secure).

Comment: @DMA57361 Seems its possible to disable safe-mode here is a link to the instructions http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/664785#answer-128337 have not tried it myself but seems like it would work.

Comment: You can’t prohibit user from messing with his user profile. **Everything** you do will be just security through obscurity.